# Change and record the value of a number of HTML buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fairly simple HTML form which has a number of HTML input buttons on it (input type="button"). The buttons use a small piece of JavaScript to change the displayed value when clicked (Yes and No). I am happy with this functionality but would like to know the best way to record the values for later submission into a database.

I have this at the moment:

```
<script>
function toggleynquestion(button)
{
  if(document.getElementById("yn_toggle").value=="Yes"){
  document.getElementById("yn_toggle").value="No";}

  else if(document.getElementById("yn_toggle").value=="No"){
  document.getElementById("yn_toggle").value="Yes";}
}
</script>
<form method="post" action="ynquestion_submit.php" name="yn_submit">
<p> Yes or No question : 
<input type="button" name="yn_question" id="yn_toggle" value="Yes" onclick="toggleynquestion(this);"/>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the best way to record the values for later submission into a database"

Comment: I think he means preparing the data to be submitted when someone clicks 'Save'

Comment: Yes this is correct. Ideally on submission ynquestion_submit.php uses $ynvariable = $_POST['yn_question'] to grab the value of the input button. Although I don't believe that doing it this way is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `hidden` form elements, they will get sent to the server just like `text` inputs:

```js
function toggleynquestion(button)
{
  if(document.getElementById("yn_toggle").value=="Yes"){
    document.getElementById("yn_toggle").value="No";
    document.getElementById("yn_answer").value="No";
  } else if(document.getElementById("yn_toggle").value=="No"){
    document.getElementById("yn_toggle").value="Yes";
    document.getElementById("yn_answer").value="Yes";
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="ynquestion_submit.php" name="yn_submit">
<p> Yes or No question : 
<input type="button" name="yn_question" id="yn_toggle" value="Yes" onclick="toggleynquestion(this);"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="yn_answer" id="yn_answer" value="Yes" />
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
  </form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the reputation to upvote your answer yet.